# Why is $\operatorname{spec}(K[x,y])-\{(x,y)\}$ not isomorphic to $\operatorname{spec} K[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is $\operatorname{spec}(K[x,y])-\{(x,y)\}$ not isomorphic to $\operatorname{spec}K[x,y]$?
I cannot see why they can't be an isomorphism between? If both of these are infinite sets there can be a bijection between them.
I might be missing some trivial argument, any help is appreciated.
I was trying to prove $\{A_k\}^{2}-\{(x,y)\}$ is not affine and I complete the argument if I am able to show the above claim.

Comment: A bijection is not necessarily a topological isomorphism.

Comment: So you're telling me that the plane is topologically isomorphic to the plane minus a point?

Comment: sorry, but how is it a plane? the plane will correspond to maximal ideals right

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122821

Comment: You're right: it's not trivial. See the answer by user1971 here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19884/regular-functions-on-the-plane-minus-a-point/19961

Comment: And on schemes, even maps which are homeomorphisms at the topological level aren't necessarily scheme isomorphisms.

Comment: I just want to show that they are not topologically isomorphic

Comment: @Billy  I don't completely understand how does it solve my problem.

Comment: See the explanation of Ravi Vakil in the section 4.4.3 of his Math 216 notes.